# Python multiple column match within pandas df & then drop rows that don't match

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with multiple time/date columns:

```
{'city': {0: 'HOUSTON', 1: 'HOUSTON', 2: 'HOUSTON', 3: 'HOUSTON', 4: 'HOUSTON'}, 'timeDate_1': {0: Timestamp('2017-07-01 08:00:00'), 1: Timestamp('2017-07-01 08:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('2017-07-01 08:00:00'), 3: Timestamp('2017-07-01 08:00:00'), 4: Timestamp('2017-07-01 08:00:00')}, 'hour': {0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 4}, 'timeDate_2': {0: Timestamp('2017-01-07 00:00:00'), 1: Timestamp('2017-01-07 00:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('2017-01-07 00:00:00'), 3: Timestamp('2017-01-07 00:00:00'), 4: Timestamp('2017-01-07 00:00:00')}}
```

I need to match across these columns - as in if `timeDate_1` equals `timeDate_2` (or the `hour` column), and drop all rows where date and time don't match up. Obviously the easiest way would be to have two different tables and just join on date/time, but I'm in too deep at this point.

The `dtypes` of each column are:

```
timeDate_1       datetime64[ns]
hour                      int64
timeDate_2       datetime64[ns]
```

Which spits out an error when I do an `isin` operation:

```
df[df['timeDate_1'].isin(['timeDate_2', 'hour']) ]

ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', 'timeDate_2')
```

What's the easiest way to do this? (Besides decoupling all the columns and doing a simple join)

Comment: maybe it would be more clear what you want if you would provide a dataframe, where some rows actually match and some don;t and then provide an expected output. Right now you have one column with dates `2017-07-01`and the other `2017-01-07`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df[
   df['timeDate_1'].isin(df['timeDate_2'])
   | df['timeDate_1'].dt.hour.isin(df['hour']) 
]
```